# Why clearInterval doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, clearinterval

I can't get `clearInterval` to work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function (e){
        var $timer = setInterval(function(){$("#Move").animate({marginTop:'+=10'}, 'fast');},1);
        if(e.keyCode == 40){ //DOWN
            $timer
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38) { //UP
            clearInterval($timer);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have just:

```
$timer
```

when key 40 is pressed down, maybe that will set the variable to null or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but at least one problem in your code is that you're storing the timer ID in a local variable, whose value will not be preserved for the next time your keydown handler runs.  Using a global instead:

```
var $timer;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function (e){
        if(e.keyCode == 40){ //DOWN
            clearInterval($timer);
            $timer = setInterval(function(){$("#Move").animate({marginTop:'+=10'}, 'fast');},1);
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38) { //UP
            clearInterval($timer);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing he might want to clear the existing interval each time before making another call to setInterval otherwise they will accumulate? I don't think re-assigning the variable stops the existing one.

Comment: I want to move a div downwards by pressing the down and stopping it  moving by pressing up

Comment: @TwanKorthout, in that case you don't need an interval at all.  Start the animation with animate() and stop it with stop().

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with "marginTop". Change it to "marginTop":"+=10px". Also move the code outside $(document).ready. Following should work.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 40){
      //console.log(2)
      $timer = setInterval(function(){
         $("#Move").animate({"marginTop":"+=10px"}, "fast")
      }, 1000);
  } 
  if(e.keyCode == 38){
    //console.log(3)
    clearInterval($timer);
  }
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `marginTop` OP has there? And why should moving the code outside document ready make any difference?

Comment: MarginTop should be in quotes. And it should be '+=10px' not '+=10'. I don't see why document ready is required. The code after making these changes works as expected.

Comment: Why should `marginTop` be in quotes? And document ready is not required for this particular case, but there's no reason _not_ to put this inside document ready.